# Considering spaces in a SQL row as null

Tags: sql, null, trim

I was suppose to get all data from the table where the column "Address" is not null
so I made a statement that look like this...

Select * from Table where Address is not null

Unfortunately, there are rows in "Address" column that has spaces so SQL cannot consider it as Null

How can I display rows where Address is not null?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most database systems have a NULLIF() function.  It was defined together with COALESCE() in the [ANSI SQL-99 standard](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-99.bnf) if not earlier.  It is implemented in at least SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite, DB2, Firebird.

```
Select * from Table where NULLIF(Address,'') is not null
```

But for me, I like this more

```
Select * from Table where Address > ''
```

It kills nulls and empty strings in one go.  It will even exclude strings that are made up entirely of spaces ('', '    ', etc).  It also retains SARGability.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: Postgres has a slightly different behaviour: [sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/558). Not sure how it is configurable.

Comment: And Oracle will treat `''` as `NULL` so (I like this one, too) the `where Address > ''` will cut off all rows.

Comment: I'd call that a bug. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/datatype-character.html states `Trailing spaces are disregarded when comparing two values of type character, and they will be removed when converting a character value to one of the other string types. Note that trailing spaces are semantically significant in character varying and text values.` I'm almost certain that they should be insignificant for both varchar and char.